# Out of order output when running multiple processes with spawn on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I'm using spawn to run multiple processes in node. Here's my code:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var log_spawn = function (out) {
    process.stdout.write(out);
};

var exec_1 = spawn('command1', ['-args1');
exec_1.stdout.on('data', log_spawn);
exec_1.stderr.on('data', log_spawn);

var exec_2 = spawn('command2', ['-args2');
exec_2.stdout.on('data', log_spawn);
exec_2.stderr.on('data', log_spawn);
```

It's working ok, but the output is out of order.

For example, if I run the two commands in the standard command line, I get the following output:

```
output_command1_line1
output_command1_line2
output_command2_line1
output_command2_line2
```

However, when I use node with spawn, I get the following:

```
output_command1_line1
output_command2_line1
output_command1_line2
output_command2_line2
```

What can I do to fix this so I see messages in the same order that I see them on a regular command line?

Comment: You might want to brush up on the concept of asynchronous functions.

Comment: I know the execution is asynchronous, I just didn't think the output would be interspersed. Even if 2 is run after 1, why would the output of 2 and 1 be mixed together? That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Because `spawn` creates multiple threads, and all of them output to the same console. Output is not buffered just because it's on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command2` starts running before `command1` finishes, therefore the output of `command1` and `command2` are interleaved. If you want `command2` to start after `command1` finishes, you can listen for the `exit` event on `exec_1`

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var log_spawn = function (out) {
    process.stdout.write(out);
};

var exec_1 = spawn('command1', ['-args1');
exec_1.stdout.on('data', log_spawn);
exec_1.stderr.on('data', log_spawn);

exec_1.stderr.on('exit', function(exitcode) {
    var exec_2 = spawn('command2', ['-args2');
    exec_2.stdout.on('data', log_spawn);
    exec_2.stderr.on('data', log_spawn);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea the output would be interleaved in that way; I figured even if 2 finished before 1 the output would be chunked. I'll explore this approach. Looks like it might get a bit unwieldy when there are many commands to run.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill if you intend to chain several commands, I recommend checking out [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: With this coding the output could still be out of order.  The 'exit' event can be posted *before* the final output is read from `exec_1.stdout` and `exec_1.stderr`.  To prevent that, also wait for the `close` events on each of `exec_1.stdout` and `exec_1.stderr`.  *(Note - `exec_1` also has a close event, which may work, but  the `exec_1.stdout` and `exec_1.stderr` certainly work. )*.   To implement that, you would definitely want to use the `async` coding feature to avoid unreadable code.